# Does the Facebook customer chat plugin support webviews within the same page?

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-messenger-bot, dialogflow-es, api-ai

I have a DialogFlow chat bot set up with Facebook integration and I am also using the [Customer Chat Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/customer-chat-plugin). For my chatbot integration I have the bot responding with URL buttons and the webview attributes. This causes the url to load within the facebook messenger phone app or web app.

I was wondering if it's possible to get the same behaviour by using the Customer Chat Plugin mentioned above? As of now when I click the URL_button from the plugin it just redirects me to a different page.

This is how my response looks:

```
{
  "facebook": {
    "attachment": {
      "type": "template",
      "payload": {
        "template_type": "button",
        "text": "WHATEVER",
        "buttons": [
          {
            "type": "web_url",
            "url": "https:// ANYURL.COM",
            "title": "Full Form"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The customer chat plugin doesn't currently support the webview. If a URL button is clicked, it will load the `fallback_url` in a separate tab.